# Discrepancy in Standard Hydrogen Electrode energy

Tags: energy

From [Absolute Electrode Potential on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_electrode_potential):

$$\ce{\frac12H2(gas) -> H+(aq) + e-(g)\quad(-(4.44\pm0.02)eV)}$$

The bond-dissociation energy of hydrogen is $\ce{4.52 eV}$:

$$\ce{\frac12H2 -> H\quad(-2.26 eV)}$$

The ionization energy of hydrogen is $\ce{13.6 eV}$:

$$\ce{H -> H+ + e- (-13.6 eV)}$$

How to address the discrepancy that the equations cannot add up in terms of energy?

---

Edit: of course I know that hydrogen ion in gas is different from hydrogen ion in aqueous solution... it is in my very essence. However, how come the enthalpy of formation of $\ce{H+(aq)}$ is zero?

Comment: There is a great deal of difference between $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{H+(aq)}$.

Comment: Enthalpy of formation, unlike the absolute potential, is very much **not** absolute. It depends on the choice of the standard state, which in this case is... guess what?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I thought the standard for hydrogen is dihydrogen gas...

Comment: True, but there is also a standard for $\ce{H+}$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin how can one element have two standards?

Comment: Well, that's a common convention. People just thought it would be easier this way. The alternative would be to define standard enthalpy for _free electron_ and use it everywhere, which is pretty un-chemical. See, you can easily have a 1M solution of $\ce{H+}$, but to handle a _mole of electrons_ is an entirely different story.

Comment: @Ivan but do you have the enthalpy change of dissolution of hydrogen ion?